# Install developed Application without developer mode

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal

I developed an Windows 10 UWP Application. This application should be used in the company, so I build it via the built in tool of Visual Studio 2015.

To do that i followed this guide : [Packaging Universal Windows apps for Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454036.aspx)

This worked fine, and i don't have a problem to install the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 via Windows Powershell when i have the "developer mode" enabled.

Now the problem:
I don't want that my employees have to activate the developer mode. They should activate the "sideload applications" option. When this option is checked the shell allways asks me to activate the developer mode and fails if I don't activate it.

So what do I have to do, that it is enough to activate the "sideload applications" option to install my developed application?

When I built the apppackage i checked the following settings:

- Do you want to build packages to upload to the Windows Store?
  ==> No
- Generate app bundle ==> Always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sideload apps is a more secure option than Developer mode because you cannot install apps on the device **without a trusted certificate**.

**Requirements**

Here's what you'll need to have:

- Devices need to be unlocked for sideloading (unlock policy enabled)
- Certificate assigned to app
- Signed app package

And here's what you'll need to do:

- Turn on sideloading - you can push a policy with an MDM provider, or
  you can use Settings.
- Trust the app - import the security certificate to the local device.
- Install the app - use PowerShell to install the app package

**How do you sideload an app on desktop**

You can sideload apps on managed or unmanaged devices.

To turn on sideloading for managed devices

- Deploy an enterprise policy.

To turn on sideloading for unmanaged devices

- Open Settings.
- Click Update & Security > For developers.
- On Use developer features, select Sideload apps.

To import the security certificate

- Open the security certificate for the appx package, and select
  Install Certificate.
- On the Certificate Import Wizard, select Local Machine.
- Import the certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities
  folder.

To install the app

- From the folder with the appx package, run the PowerShell
  Add-AppxPackage command to install the appx package.

Source: https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/windows/deploy/sideload-apps-in-windows-10

Comment: First thanks, But do you have any hints for the points: "Certificate assigned to app" and "Signed app package"?

Comment: Maybe this can help, http://sertacozercan.com/2015/03/how-to-manually-sign-windows-10-uap-apps-for-sideloading/

Comment: This didn't solved my problem. It handles a complete other situation (in addition it is for the preview)...

Comment: In the following article you can find a more complete explanation on how to use a self signed certificate. http://www.howtogeek.com/250041/how-to-convert-a-windows-desktop-app-to-a-universal-windows-app/

Comment: Following the steps in the link, i get the same result: He asks me to activate the Developer mode

Comment: When does it ask you to activate developer mode?

Comment: When adding the package

Comment: @Erwin So, just to make sure that I get it, we need a trusted certificate (not self signed) to be able to sideload apps?