# Installing sideloading uwp package

Tags: uwp

I created sideloading uwp package, chosen for him e-commerce certificate, but when i installing him, the package requires to be included developer mode, sideloading mode not suitable. What's wrong?

Comment: Have you created the package for the Release configuration?

Comment: Hi, this can be seen by parsing `Add-AppDevPackage.ps1`, in the script, it will check if the current computer is in developer mode. So it is currently recommended to open the developer mode instead of the side loading mode.

Comment: Martin, yes i created for release configuration.
Richard, what is name for sideloading mode to change to it in the script?

if ($GetDeveloperLicense -or $CertificatePath)
{
    DoElevatedOperations //// i think this is developer mode
}
else
{
    DoStandardOperations
    PrintMessageAndExit $UiStrings.Success $ErrorCodes.Success
}

Comment: @Mind Hi, maybe this case will solve your problem, he encountered the same problem and provided the code in PowerShell: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597193/cannot-sideload-win10-uwp-application-without-developer-mode-developer-license)

Comment: @Richard Zhang - MSFT, yes it works. Thank you.